# How to efficiently convert character encoding in Channel?

Tags: java, performance, character-encoding, nio

I need to accept streams with different encodings and transcode them to single predefined encoding (e.g. UTF-8). I know how to do this with (`InputStream`)`Reader` / (`OutputStream`)`Writer` combo and array buffer, but this time I'm dealing with `ByteChannel`'s. Naturally, I was looking into `CharsetDecoder` / `CharsetEncoding` solution, but the best I came with is:

```
public static void copy(ReadableByteChannel rbc, Charset in, 
        WritableByteChannel wbc, Charset out) throws IOException {
    ByteBuffer b1 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(BUFFER_SIZE);
    CharBuffer cb = CharBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE);
    ByteBuffer b2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(BUFFER_SIZE);

    CharsetDecoder decoder = in.newDecoder();
    decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);
    CharsetEncoder encoder = out.newEncoder();
    encoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);

    while( rbc.read(b1)!=-1 ){
        b1.flip();
        decoder.decode(b1, cb, false);
        cb.flip();
        encoder.encode(cb, b2, false);
        b2.flip();
        wbc.write(b2);
        b2.compact();
        cb.compact();
        b1.compact();
    }
    b1.flip();
    while (b1.hasRemaining()){
        decoder.decode(b1, cb, true);
        cb.flip();
        encoder.encode(cb, b2, false);
        b2.flip();
        wbc.write(b2);
        b2.compact();
        cb.compact();
    }
    decoder.decode(b1, cb, true);
    decoder.flush(cb);
    cb.flip();
    while (cb.hasRemaining()){
        encoder.encode(cb, b2, true);
        b2.flip();
        wbc.write(b2);
        b2.compact();
    }
    encoder.encode(cb, b2, true);
    encoder.flush(b2);
    b2.flip();
    while (b2.hasRemaining()){
        wbc.write(b2);
    }
}
```

Since this method is "workhorse" in project, I must be absolutely sure that it will finish no matter what combination of BUFFER_SIZE, encodings and blocking device for output is given.

My questions are:

- Is there better way of buffer draining instead of these cascade of while loops?
- Is it OK to ignore `encode()` / `decode()` results (for overflows and underflows)?

Of course, any alternative idea is welcomed. :)

Answer (score 0):

To improve performance of above code:

1. Cache byte/char buffers in a thread local or as fields. Allocating chunks of memory is expensive.
2. Direct byte buffers are good performers for IO but bad performers for encoding/decoding which has an optimized implementation for heap buffers. You might get better performance by copying to/from heap byte buffers for the decode/encode operations.
3. You can skip encode/decode when charset is the same.
4. Minimize calls to compact.
5. You seem to have redundant decode/encode operations after the buffer have nothing remaining.
6. Byte buffer size should be 4 time the char buffer size, chars can be 1-4 bytes. Also allocating the byte buffers to be multiples of page size(usually 4k) can help IO performance.

Most importantly, write a benchmark with realistic data and use it as a means to measure performance improvements. If you don't measure you'll never know what worked.